# Get users current apprequests

Tags: facebook, graph

I'm trying to get a users current app requests, (requests they have received), so I can pull the message text from them for a message tab in a facebook game, so far all I have been able to do is pull the generic notification information (" sent you a request in ").

any advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call the Graph API with the following request:

https://graph.facebook.com/{UID}/apprequests

...where {UID} is the UID of the users requests you wish to retrieve.

This url should help - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/